# Configure a different Copyright profile for different Java (maven) modules in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, licensing

I am using Intellij Idea 2022.3.2, Community Edition, and I wonder if I can set a different Copyright Profile to different (maven) modules of my project.

(Note that I have not been able to add the copyright header to my existing source files that did not have that header)

I have been looking for it on the internet, but I have not been successful with that ...

So the questions are two:

- How can I add a Copyright profile (header) to my existing files without that header ?
- Can diferent (maven) modules be configured with different Copyright profiles?

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: I cannot understand what is happening with the answer to my question ... What is happening? why have them erased it? The answer seemed to make sense, and the replier seemed to be able to help me with that ... but ... what now ? nothing ? Why have you removed that answer?

Comment: Who is responsible of having erased that answer? Can I know it?

Comment: Or it was simply the black hand ?

Comment: Los poderes fácticos contra el piltrafilla ... qué grande ...

Comment: do you know you are aligned with assassins?

Comment: I am only asking ... as I think you do not know the details of the situation ...

Comment: I suffer from harassment in my real life and it seems that this harassment has reached this far

Answer (score 0):

- create a shared scope in "Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes" and include the desired module into it
- create a profile in "Preferences | Editor | Copyright | Copyright Profiles"
- assign profile to a scope in "Preferences | Editor | Copyright"